# Find non-matches in HTML select list against JSON list using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, filter, selectlistitem

I have a SelectList coming back from my MVC ActionResult as Json data:

the controller:

```
  public JsonResult _ConnectorFilters(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3) {
      //collecting selectlist items ex: 
      listConatenated.Add(newSelectListItem {Value = "Category1", Text = "attribute1"};
      listConatenated.Add(newSelectListItem {Value = "Category1", Text = "attribute2"}
      listConatenated.Add(newSelectListItem {Value = "Category2", Text = "attribute3"};

     return Json(new SelectList(listConcatenated, "Value", "Text"));

 }
```

I would like to find each of the `option` items in the `<select/>` list of my view that have the same `value` as the matching category coming back in my JsonResult, but *non-matching* Text, and change the "disable" property of each of them to "true."

To reiterate, if I have the following in my current  list:

```
  <select class="Category1Class">
     <option value="Category1">attribute100<option/>
     <option value="Category1">attribute40<option/>
     <option value="Category1">attribute1<option/>
     <option value="Category1">attribute2<option/>
  </select>
```

Then the jquery function I'm trying to write into the `success:` result function would return:

```
  <select class="Category1Class">
     <option value="Category1" disabled>attribute100<option/>
     <option value="Category1" disabled>attribute40<option/>
     <option value="Category1">attribute1<option/>
     <option value="Category1">attribute2<option/>
  </select>
```

I hope this makes sense. Not sure how to begin when comparing against the Json result. Thank you in advance & please let me know if I could be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming response looks something like:

```
[
 { "Value": "Category1","Text": "attribute1"},
 { "Value": "Category1","Text": "attribute2"}
]
```

You can loop through response using `each()` and use `filter()` to isolate the matching DOM elements:

```
var $opts= $('select.Category1Class option');
/* loop over response as "data" */
$.each(data, function( index, item){
   $opts.filter(function(){
       /* return boolean based on matches */
       return $(this).text() === item.Text && this.value === item.Value;
      /* disable resultant collection */
   }).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: this looks like just what I need--but I am looking to change the *non-matches* in the list. That would be return the items in `data` that have matching `Value` but non-matching `Text` and disable those `$opts`. If you could alter your example slightly that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: just change the conditional return accordingly

Comment: woudl the statement: `$(this).text() === !selectItem.Text` suffice as the appopriate "not" syntax?

Comment: more like `!$(this).text() === item.Text && !this.value === item.Value;`

Comment: hmm...it is still not filtering/disabling the options with the text that doesn't exist in the Json result. In my example those would be: `<option value="Category1" disabled>attribute100<option/>` and
     `<option value="Category1" disabled>attribute40<option/>`

Comment: My bad. Please disregard. Works like a charm. Was using `$(this).value()` thinking they syntax was analogous. Thank you kindly.